# Could not resolve proxy: proxy.server.com

Tags: github, virtualbox

I am new to virtual box and also to GitHub

I am trying `git clone` command from the Ubuntu terminal, but I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal:Unable to access: https://github.com/argus-classroom/os-s20-baberghafoor.git/
Could not resolve proxy: proxy.server.com
```

How can I avoid this error message?

Comment: use this command export HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_server:proxy_port, use the working right server. refer this https://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-for-apt-from-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Even before trying to git clone anything, you need to make sure your VirtualBox OS session does have access to internet.

First, make sure the settings associated to said session in VirtualBox are correct. SEe "[VirtualBox: How to set up networking so both host and guest can access internet and talk to each other](https://serverfault.com/q/225155/783)"

Then, check if:

- you can ping said proxy (`ping http://proxy.server.com`)
- need credentials to use that proxy (username/password)

Once everything is working, then you can try and use Git.